# Any Mobile Framework without jQuery or Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile is working for my site but slow. Cause of the slowness turned out to be jquery. We searched an alternative but most of them still uses javascript/jquery.

Question: Is there any other framework for mobile with better performance?

Comment: Any car without engine or metallic parts.

Comment: What version are you using? jQM is now on Beta 3 using jQuery 1.6.2 Also with the release of jQM version 1.0 you can download only the parts of jQM you need to reduce files size and load times as well

Comment: @markus you are right. I changed my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Zepto: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto

It still uses JavaScript but with a really small footprint.

Answer (score 3):

Considering Javascript is the core language all web browsers use for programatic changes, unless you want to only change the Visuals via CSS and what it has to offer, I believe you are stuck.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I want to use CSS only. Do you know any reusable CSS for mobile?

Comment: Sorry I do not, I only use Jquery & Jquery mobile.